# what code should I write to replace multiple "and" statements in one line?

Tags: python

here is the code I am trying to fix:
the program runs but never returns covid negative even if I answer with a no, what would the correct syntax be to write this statement?

```
elif question1 and question2 and question3 and question4 and question5 and question6 == "NO":
    print(name)
    print(gender)
    print(number)
    print(adress)
    print("COVID-19 Negative")
    neg_counter = neg_counter + 1
```

Comment: Looks like this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: It must be because this clause is skipped by a previous if returning true, can you paste the full if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually won't properly run at all – it'll compute as something like this:

```py
(((question1 and question2) and question3) and question4)...
```

As in it's not actually calculating what I think you want, which is to see if any of them are `=="NO"`.

One way to do this is:

```py
elif "NO" in (question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6):
```

**EDIT:**
Since OP has clarified and wants to check if all of them are `=="NO"` or not, we can do this:

```py
elif question1 == question2 == question3 == question4 == question5 == question6 == "NO":
```

Comment: I am not trying to see just if any of them are == "NO" but to see if ALL of them are == "NO". That's why I used all those and statements. How would I be able to check if all of them were == "NO"